# Wix installer auto update

Tags: wix, windows-installer, auto-update

I have an installer, of a WPF application using c# created using Wix, and I would like to update it automatically or when the user clicks on "update to latest version".

Does anyone how to do it and have any example of it?

Comment: You could have a look at the source code for the wix toolset installer itself? Their installer offers this functionality.

Comment: Your question implies you are installing some sort of program(s). That program would have to do the update. So, please [edit] your question to indicate the language you would use for that.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Do you know any guide or tutorial where I can start? I could not find nothing on Wix documentation.